# How to view images based on tab selection in android

Tags: android

Hi 
I have created a program to fetch and display some images in gridview inside tabview stored on device.

1. MyAppfolder

   1.1. Fruitsfolder

   1.1.1.apple.jpg

   1.1.2.Grapes.jpg

   2.1. Vegetablefolder

   2.1.1.tomato.jpg

   2.1.2.cucumber.jpg

This is the folder structure of my application . My main folder is MyApp. It contains subfolder named Fruitfolder and Vegetable folder.These name are used for creating tabs(dynamically).What i need is to display images in gridview from the folder when i select the folder named tab .
ie when i click on vegetable folder tab view its corresponding gridview with images tomato.jpg and cucumber.jpg.

These folders are currently saved inside sdcard.

Any idea to accomplish this.please reply .thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

You can use the '[Environment](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/Environment.html)'-Class to see if there is an SDcard and to get it's root directory as a 'java.io.File'-Object.

You should be able to create a File-Object on your desired folder and then list all files (with your desired format) using the '[listFiles()](http://download.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/api/java/io/File.html#listFiles%28java.io.FileFilter%29)'-method.

After that, you can use the '[FileInputStream](http://download.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/api/java/io/FileInputStream.html#FileInputStream%28java.io.File%29)'-Class (for example) to get an InputStream from which you can read your Picture. A Tutorial on this can be found [here](http://www.brighthub.com/mobile/google-android/articles/64048.aspx).